# Set image source dynamically in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am importing these images:

```
import Image1 from './assets/image1.png';
import Image2 from './assets/image2.png';
```

I am then using them in JSX:

```
<img src={Image1} alt="image1"/>
<img src={Image2} alt="image2"/>
```

The problem is that I would like to be able to set the source dinamically, like this, for example:

```
<img src={`Image${1}`} alt="image1"/>
```

but of course a string won't work.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you just trying to change which image is displayed based on some logic?

Comment: Can you describe your use case in greater details? Aren't you re-inventing image lazy load?

Answer (score 0):

You could store them all in some object with keys and then use the key to reference the image:

```
const images = {
  Image1,
  Image2,
  ...etc
}
<img src={images[`Image${1}`]} alt="image1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have logic to determine which image to show. Here I wrote a function called `chooseImage` to help dynamically choose image based on some logic.

```
import Image1 from './assets/image1.png';
import Image2 from './assets/image2.png';

export default function App() {

  const chooseImage = () => {
    // logic for choosing image goes here....
    if (true) {
       return Image1;
    }

    return Image2;
  }

  return (
      <img src={chooseImage()}/>
  );
}
```